# Algorithm to transform from Absolute to Relative position

Tags: javascript, css, html, algorithm

I have some `<div>` elements which are positioned absolute inside a relative parent:

[image: Divs with absolute position]

I need to display these fields on a page, in the same position, but also using the page flow.

For example, if one div gets removed, the ones below it should move up:

[image]

Page flow doesn't work if they still have absolute position.

Are there any algorithms / css tricks that i can use in order to display the divs in the same position and also using the page flow?

---

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLYeU/)

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="element" style="width: 300px; top: 10px; left: 0;"></div>
<div class="element" style="width: 300px; top: 10px; left: 310px;"></div>
<div class="element" style="width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 0;"></div>
<div class="element" style="width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 310px;"></div>
<div class="element" style="width: 610px; top: 90px; left: 0px;" id="elementToRemove"></div>
<div class="element" style="width: 300px; top: 130px; left: 0;"></div>
<button id="deleteButton" style="position: absolute; top: 170px;">Delete</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#deleteButton").click(function () {
    $("#elementToRemove").remove();
});
```

CSS:

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: why are they positioned absolute in the relative parent? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: @Gotschi They are absolute because i can drag them to move them where i want to (is a form designer)

Comment: @samitha: I've added a jsfiddle link

Comment: how do you implement the drag(&drop) functionality? jquery or native html5 or ...?

Comment: you need to automatically move other elements right ?

Comment: @samitha Yes, this needs to happen automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `top` css attribute in order to move elements up or down.

If that number does not change, then nothing will move.

You can change it based of the deleted element's height.

So in your case you can do something like this:

```
$("#deleteButton").click(function () {
    var removeElement = $("#elementToRemove");
    var nextElement = removeElement.next();
    nextElement.css('top', removeElement.css('top'));
    removeElement.remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/zLYeU/2/

Comment: I know, unfortunately, creating an algorithm that detects all the below elements and moving them up is complicated, and i am hoping for a better solution

Comment: jquery `next()` gets the next element in DOM, not the actually one which is bellow. And also, this needs to happen recursively for all the elements below